# dynamic response function for Uploadify

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, extjs, uploadify

**Opening**

I have several forms (in this case two) that are located in tabs using Ext-JS.
I also have jQuery framework which I use for main javascript script/programming.
last is an Javascript object global instance(single) that holds state.

the instance called obj have properties of:
obj.fileID;
obj.manID;
obj.womenID;
**method**
 1. now I issue a post to the DB with fileID and using it's response i make a new object.
that holds current file,women and man IDs.
 2. after that I want to upload a file (an image in this case).
using Uploadify I bind to an input element of file type.

I wanted to either update scriptData when building that new object.
or catch the onComplete and use that.
there I want to issue another post to the PHP file that will update
 the DB for location of the file uploaded
**problem**

started when the non-visible input tag could not be updated.
 
because flash had to loaded again.

I don't mind using a different flash uploader but I request a solution for this problem.

Arye.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are hiding the SWF. In FF and WebKit, if you do a display:none on a SWF, then display:block (or whatever) the SWF reloads. And I don't think it's something that will change.

If you need to hide the SWF move it off the page with something like: left:-9999px

Also, I'm sure swfUploader allows you to post variables along with the file. So perhaps this can be done in one call.

Comment: if I can update it's variables than it's fine, problem comes when it's hiding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to hide it.

```
visibility:hidden;
left:-9999px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Any of these should work, `display:none` will make it inactive on the DOM in most cases, so it's best to avoid using it when you need to update the element.

**Option #1** - Will not effect positioning on the DOM

```
position:absolute;
left:-9999px;
```

**Option #2** - Also will not effect positioning on the DOM.

```
position:absolute;
visibility:hidden;
```

**Option #3** - Will effect position on the DOM.

```
margin-left:-9999px;
```

or

```
visibility:hidden;
```

Comment: the swf object regenerates itself when hidden ,